# File lastModified() returns Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969

Tags: java, time, file-io, java-time

I was doing some testing with files like this:

```
    public Date findFileDate(){
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Date date = new Date(file.lastModified());
    return date;
}
```

When I print `date` it says: `Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969`. After some research I found that is my "time since the Unix Epoch" according to my time zone, but I am confused why I would get this output when no file exists at my `filePath`. Why would it not return `null` or `0`?

Comment: It *is* returning 0... the Unix epoch occurred at 7pm on December 31st 1969 in EST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `file.lastModified()` is returning 0. That's the Unix epoch

In your particular time zone (Eastern US by the looks of it), local time at the Unix epoch was 5 hours behind UTC, so it was 7pm on December 31st 1969.

To confirm this, just separate your `Date` declaration and assignment into two:

```
long lastModifiedMillis = file.lastModified();
Date date = new Date(lastModifiedMillis);
```

Now if you examine `lastModifiedMillis` I'm sure you'll find a value of 0, as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified--):

> **Returns**
>   A `long` value representing the time the file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970), or `0L` if the file does not exist or if an I/O error occurs

Comment: Thanks I was using the Date() rather than the long I wanted

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using `java.time`, modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // If you need the corresponding date-time representing your timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
1969-12-31T19:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the time-line. The `Z` in the output stands for Zulu which represents UTC (timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>